# Serializer for class 'MultipartBody' is not found

Tags: android, kotlin, ktor, ktor-client

Hi I am trying to make multiform request with ktor but I am getting above error. How can I serilize MultiPartBody?

```
   val body = MultipartBody.Builder().setType(MultipartBody.FORM)
    .addFormDataPart("choice","John Wick")
    .addFormDataPart("image",path,
        File(path).asRequestBody("application/octet-stream".toMediaType()))
    .build()

val httpResponse = client.post {
    url("https://example.com")
    setBody(body)
    header("Content-Type","application/json")
    header("Authorization", "Bearer key")
}
```

Comment: I recommend deleting this line. header("Content-Type","application/json")

Comment: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Fail to prepare request body for sending. 
The body type is: class okhttp3.MultipartBody, with Content-Type: null.

If you expect serialized body, please check that you have installed the corresponding plugin(like `ContentNegotiation`) and set `Content-Type` header.
 at io.ktor.client.plugins.HttpSend$Plugin$install$1.invokeSuspend(HttpSend.kt:88) @ΓDΛ I am getting this error if I remove content type header

Comment: header(HttpHeaders.ContentType, ContentType.Application.OctetStream)


Could you try adding this?

Comment: Fail to prepare request body for sending. 
The body type is: class okhttp3.MultipartBody, with Content-Type: application/octet-stream.
                                                                                                    
If you expect serialized body, please check that you have installed the corresponding plugin(like `ContentNegotiation`) and set `Content-Type` header  @ΓDΛ

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ktor cannot send directly an object of the `okhttp3.MultipartBody` class. Please use the `MultiPartFormDataContent` class instead:

```
val body = MultiPartFormDataContent(
    formData {
        append("choice", "John Wick")
        append("image", File(path).readBytes(), Headers.build {
            append(HttpHeaders.ContentType, "application/octet-stream")
            append(HttpHeaders.ContentDisposition, "filename=\"file\"")
        })
    }
)
```